# VBScript IE Navigate flags - same window/same tab

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, navigation

In VBScript / IE, I'm reading a list of URL's from a text file and trying to use the navigate2 flags to open each in the same window/same tab.  I can open in a NEW window or a NEW tab, but want to open within the same window and tab so no new windows and no new tabs are created.  Not sure which navigation2 flag achieves this, if any.

I've read that using _top or _self accomplishes this, but when I try:

```
ie.navigate2 url, 1, _top
```

... it errors "invalid character".  Guessing I'm implementing this incorrectly...

Answer (score 0):

Should be `ie.navigate2 url, 0, "_top"`

FYI: [BrowserNavConstants enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360(v=vs.85).aspx). Contains values used by the `IWebBrowser2::Navigate` and  [`IWebBrowser2::Navigate2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752094(v=vs.85).aspx) methods. In `VBScript` terms:

```
Const navOpenInNewWindow = &h01, _
      navNoHistory       = &h02, _
      navNoReadFromCache = &h04, _
      navNoWriteToCache  = &h08, _
      navAllowAutosearch = &h10, _
      navBrowserBar      = &h20, _
      navHyperlink       = &h40, _
      navEnforceRestricted = &h80, _
      navNewWindowsManaged = &h0100, _
      navUntrustedForDownload = &h0200, _
      navTrustedForActiveX = &h0400, _
      navOpenInNewTab      = &h0800, _
      navOpenInBackgroundTab = &h1000, _
      navKeepWordWheelText   = &h2000, _
      navVirtualTab          = &h4000, _
      navBlockRedirectsXDomain = &h8000, _
      navOpenNewForegroundTab = &h010000
```

Comment: Thank you.  No longer erroring, but still not working.  Still opens new window.

Comment: This also seems to open a new window.  Using IE 11 in case it matters.  Using "_target", it loads the URL in the same tab/window, but ALSO opens another blank window.  Thought I was onto something...